# Displaying Instagram Video and description within a RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram

I'm working on a small project where a User can search for a location and get all the photos taken with that location ID.  I'm having problems displaying the videos and description but I do have photos displayed. Here is some code:

First the image: (client in these examples are variables, `"client = Instagram.location_search(@foursquare_id).first"`)

```
pry(main)> client[0][:images][:standard_resolution][:url]
=> "http://distilleryimage2.s3.amazonaws.com/ca482e74ed1e11e2996e22000a1f98fe_7.jpg"
```

In my application I have this in my views:

```
<%= image_tag photo.images.standard_resolution.url %>
```

Displaying my photos fine. (Although I can only show a small amount, anyone know how to fix that? I have count set at 16 yet it randomly shows 5 or 8 or whatever it wants it seems.)

This is for video:

```
pry(main)> client[0][:videos][:standard_resolution][:url]
=> "http://distilleryimage2.s3.amazonaws.com/ca482e74ed1e11e2996e22000a1f98fe_101.mp4"
```

I assumed the code to display videos as well would be the same:

```
<%= video_tag photo.videos.standard_resolution.url %>
```

But I am getting a NoMethodError on "standard_resolution". I'm not even sure the video_tag is doing anything, the image_tag is necessary though for images(I dont know why that is).

I have an identical problem with description. In pry or rails console I can display them fine but I cant get out of errors on my site. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Heres my github repo https://github.com/Jamalp/foodstagram

Comment: Welcome to GitHub! Please review this tutorial on [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! Also, make sure to put your code in code blocks.

Comment: Omgosh. That should say "Welcome to  Stack Overflow!" Brainfart.